# Are there ‘product expressions’ for sequences of binomial coefficients similar to the ‘product expression’ for the central binomial coefficients?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

If we want a central binomial coefficient, for n greater than zero we have a ‘nice’ expression $${2n \choose n} =\prod_{k=1}^{n}{(4-\frac{2}{k})}$$ which is term-wise rational and produces each binomial coefficient matching ${2n \choose n}$ along the way.

But supposed we desired a similar expression for some other ‘linear pattern’ in Pascal’s triangle, like ${3n \choose n}$, or ${5n \choose 2n}$. Perhaps it is term-wise algebraic rather than rational, sans any ‘bespoke encoding of a sequence into a magic constant’ horsery. Can our desire be satisfied under any conditions? If so, how, and if not, why?

---

**Edit:**

Here is one other such expression I have been able to derive, in case anyone comes across this and is interested:

$${4n \choose 2n} = \prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2(4k-1)(4k-3)}{k(2k-1)}}$$

And generally:

$${an \choose n} = \prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{a(k)_{a}}{(a-1)(k)_{(a-1)}}} $$

Comment: Something like ${3n\choose n}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{3n+1-k}{k} =\prod_{k=1}^n(\left(\frac{3n+1}{k}-1\right)$?

Comment: That is a nice one, thank you for sharing! I am interested to know how that can be derived, not only for ${3n \choose n}$ but for any such ${an \choose bn}$ with $b < a$, especially if it is possible without the term depending on $n$.

Comment: I now see the general ‘multiplicative formula’ using a falling factorial, and how I could plug in the $a$ and $b$. I would still like to see if there is a way to avoid having the terms depend upon the upper bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that for any $${an \choose bn}$$ with $0 \le b \le a$ we have the degree $(a-1)$ rational curve $$R_{a,b}(x)  = \frac{(ax)^{\underline{a}}}{(bx)^{\underline{b}}((a-b)x)^{\underline{a-b}}}$$ such that $${a(n-1) \choose b(n-1)}R_{a,b}(n) = {an \choose bn} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} R_{a,b}(k).$$ I do not have a rigorous proof for this; I just discovered the pattern through computation.

Answer (score 1):

From $${2n \choose n} =\prod_{k=1}^{n}{(4-\frac{2}{k})}$$ one can obviously  get 
$${4n \choose 2n} =\prod_{k=1}^{2n}{(4-\frac{2}{k})}$$ and

$${6n \choose 3n} =\prod_{k=1}^{3n}{(4-\frac{2}{k})}$$
Which are not new formulas.

In general we have $$  {m \choose n} =\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{(1+\frac{d}{n-k})} $$ where $d=m-n.$